# Updating to Windows 10

Tags: update

I wanted to update to windows 10 on Lumia and at first it was smooth. Later the download got stuck at 8% I've been trying again and again but still nothing works.
Someone please help me?
Also I rebooted my mobile.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12995/106

Comment: Question is not clear. Describe which phone you are using? which version you currently have? you want to update to stable release or insider?